# Output data from form on the page react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I am writing todo app. There are main files in my directory now:

**App** (rendering main page with header and buttons)

```
 export default class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { triggerText: 'Create a task' };
}
propTypes = {
  triggerText: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

render() {
  const { triggerText } = this.state;
  const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
  return (
   <div className="App">
     <header className="App-header">
     <h1>To Do List</h1>
     <div id="tasksList">
      <span className="tasks active">Tasks</span>
    </div>
    <div id="categoriesList">
    <span className="categories">Categories</span>
    </div>
    <div>
    <Container triggerText={triggerText} onSubmit={handleSubmit} /> // creates modal dialog and uses TodoForm
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="container" className="container">
      <TodoBox tasks={[]}/>
    </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

**TodoForm** (create a form)

```
export default class TodoForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { value: '', tasks: [] };
}
propTypes = {
handleSubmit: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

handleRemove = (currentTaskId) => (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { tasks } = this.state;
  this.setState({ tasks: tasks.filter(({ id }) => id !== currentTaskId) });
};

handleChange = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { value, tasks } = this.state;
  const newTask = { id: uniqueId(), text: value };
  this.setState({ value: '', tasks: [newTask, ...tasks] });
}

render() {
  const { value } = this.state;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="text"><strong>Create a task</strong></label>
        <input
        type="text"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        value={value}
        required
        className="form-control"
        id="text"
        placeholder="I am going..."
      />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <button type="submit" className="form-control btn btn-primary">Add</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    );
  }
}
```

**TodoBox** (generating list of tasks)

```
class Item extends React.Component {
  propTypes = {
  onRemove: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  task: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
 render() {
    const { task, onRemove } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div>
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={onRemove}>-</button>
        </div>
        <div className="col-10">{task.text}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

  export default class TodoBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }
   propTypes = {
    tasks: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }
   render() {
    const { tasks } = this.props;
    return (
     <div className="item">
       {tasks.map((task) => (
       <div key={task.id}>
       <Item task={task} onRemove={this.handleRemove} />
       <hr />
     </div>
     ))}
   </div>
   );
 }
}
```

And the question is: how I can pass the state from TodoForm to TodoBox in App (it is initialize as an empty array now). I want to output tasks at the bottom of the same page in container after header element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function (addTodo) in App component and pass it down to the TodoForm component. In TodoForm component you can invoke the addTodo function from props and send the todoValue as arguments `props.addTodo(todoValue)`. In addTodo function in App component you can update the todoValue to state. Once you update the state it will re-render the App component, then the TodoBox component will call with the updated todoValue value.

**Note:** But it is not best practice. The best practice is to use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Thank you for help. I used React Context and it works very well. I think Redux is better than this way but I didn't use this library yet